# onSaveInstanceState doesn't get called in sub activity

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I've two Activities:

**A.class**

**B.class**

A.class *extends* B.class.

I tried to understand what's happening by putting Log messeges inside android application life cycle methods. This is what I get.

```
onCreate B.class 10399440 (Open activity)
onCreate A.class 10399440 (Open activity)
onResume B.class 10399440 (Open activity)
onPause  B.class 10399440 (Go to background using "home" button)
--- Open my application ---
onCreate B.class 114082588 (new instance)
```

As you can see, I get a new B.class instance and as you can imagine, I lose all previous data, so application crashes. I was thinking about using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` to avoid this problem, but

**B.class**

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LogUtil.debug(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState B.class" + hashCode());
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    LogUtil.debug(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState B.class" + hashCode());
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    LogUtil.debug(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState B.class " + hashCode());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    LogUtil.debug(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState B.class" + hashCode());
}
```

doesn't return any log messeges, which makes me think that onSaveInstanceState doesn't get called. Why so and what is the correct way to save data (in my case) when I go from:

```
Activity opened -> background [home button] -> open application
```

Comment: if you rotate the screen instead, does the onSave/RestoreInstance state get called? onSaveInstanceState is called after onPause is called, and before onStop.

Comment: In this case, application is for TV. (I highly doubt that it changes anything, except, I can't rotate screen, lol)
Well, yes, I mean, it should get called after onPause(), but it doesn't, which makes me confused.